# How to calculate the fraction of sequence that matches given datatables with start and end coordinates?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, sequence, matching

Given two datatables with start and end coordinates for sequences of integers:

```
df1 <- data.table(CAT = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
              START = c(1, 11, 21, 1, 21, 41, 1, 11, 21),
              END = c(10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 60, 10, 20, 30)
)
df2 <- data.table(CAT = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3)),
              START = c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 1, 11, 21),
              END = c(5, 17, 23, 38, 48, 54, 9, 17, 26)
)
```

How can I count the number of integers in each sequence in `df1` that are within the start and end coordinates of any sequence in `df2` with matching `CAT`? I am currently using a for loop:

```
seq2 <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))
df1$MATCH <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df2_sub <- subset(df2, df2$CAT == df1$CAT[i])
  df2_int <- unlist(seq2(from = df2_sub$START, to = df2_sub$END))
  df1_int <- seq(df1$START[i], df1$END[i])
  df1$MATCH[i] <- length(na.omit(match(df1_int, df2_int)))
}
```

which returns

```
df1
```

> ```
>    CAT START END MATCH
> 1:   A     1  10     5
> 2:   A    11  20     7
> 3:   A    21  30     3
> 4:   B     1  20     0
> 5:   B    21  40     8
> 6:   B    41  60    12
> 7:   C     1  10     9
> 8:   C    11  20     7
> 9:   C    21  30     6
> ```

However, the datatables and vectors I am applying this to are very large? Is anyone able to suggest a way to improve performance? Perhaps using `data.table`?

Comment: See ```foverlaps()``` from data.table.

Comment: No, there is no row-wise correspondence.

Comment: I haven't tested this for all cases, but try this `df2[df1, sum(END - pmax(x.START, i.START) + 1, na.rm = TRUE), on = .(CAT, START >= START, START <= END), by = .EACHI]` I think it should be very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create sequences which are collapsed afterwards.

As mentioned by [Cole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358829/how-to-calculate-the-fraction-of-sequence-that-matches-given-datatables-with-sta#comment99322970_56358829), the `foverlaps()` function can be used to identify overlapping sequences. With some simple arithmetic, the lengths of the overlaps can be calculated which are aggregated for each row of `df1`, finally:

```
library(data.table)
foverlaps(df1[, rn := .I], setkey(df2, CAT, START, END))[
  , ovl := (pmin(END, i.END) - pmax(START, i.START) + 1)][
    , .(MATCH = sum(ovl)), by = .(rn)][
      is.na(MATCH), MATCH := 0][]
```

> ```
>    rn MATCH
> 1:  1     5
> 2:  2     7
> 3:  3     3
> 4:  4     0
> 5:  5     8
> 6:  6    12
> 7:  7     9
> 8:  8     7
> 9:  9     6
> ```

The development version 1.12.3 of `data.table` comes with a new `nafill()` function:

```
library(data.table) # version 1.12.3
foverlaps(df1[, rn := .I], setkey(df2, CAT, START, END))[
  , ovl := (pmin(END, i.END) - pmax(START, i.START) + 1)][
    , .(MATCH = sum(ovl)), by = .(rn)][
      , MATCH := nafill(MATCH, fill = 0)][]
```

Answer (score 2):

The first things you need to know is that you use for all your line in df1 your function seq2 which is for the perfomance is very bad.

This is the solution I propose, I haven't tested it with an very large dataset for the performance.

```
seq2 <- Vectorize(seq.default, vectorize.args = c("from", "to"))

df2_sub = df2[, sequence = unlist( seq2(from = START, to = END) ), by = CAT]

f = function(cat, start, end){
  df2_sub[CAT == cat, length( intersect(seq(start, end), sequence) )]
}

df1[, MATCH := f(CAT, START, END), by = 1:nrow(df1)]
```

It work if the two table df1 and df2 are data.table.